# Excel Column Sort does not sort comment

Tags: excel, sorting, comments

when I sort a column in excel 2007, the comments in corresponding cells not get sorted with the data. Atfer sorting, comments show up still on the cell they belong, but data is different. How can I move comments with the data while sorting?
I made sure that automatic forumla calculation is switched to on. So that's not the reason

Answer (score 0):

I was really stupid to post this question, sorry for that
I tried to sort a large table and I didn't realize that the column which contained the comments was not within the sort range.
Very stupid ... sorry for this